# com.sun.jna.Native$1 uncaughtException

Tags: java, jna, mouse-hook

Recently,I try to get information of mouse by jna because my project need this function.The.But there is a exception occur when I run the following code.I have google ,but there is nothing about problem.I'm confused,please help me ~~

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HOOKPROC;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;

public class MouseHook implements Runnable{

    public static final int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 512;
    private static HHOOK hhk;
    private static LowLevelMouseProc mouseHook;
    final static User32 lib = User32.INSTANCE;
    private boolean [] on_off=null;

    public MouseHook(boolean [] on_off){
        this.on_off = on_off;
    }

    public interface LowLevelMouseProc extends HOOKPROC {
        LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT lParam);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new MouseHook(new boolean[] {true})).start();
    }

    public static class MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT implements
        Structure.ByReference {
        };
        public User32.POINT pt;
        public int wHitTestCode;
        public User32.ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
        mouseHook = new LowLevelMouseProc() {
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam,
                    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT info) {
                SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String fileName=df1.format(new Date());
                String time=df2.format(new Date());
                BufferedWriter bw1=null;
                BufferedWriter bw2=null;
                try {
                    bw1=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(".//log//"+fileName+"_Mouse.txt"),true));
                    bw2=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(".//log//"+fileName+"_Common.txt"),true));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (on_off[0] == false) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (nCode >= 0) {
                    switch (wParam.intValue()) {
                    case MouseHook.WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                        try {
                            bw1.write(time+"  ####  "+"x=" + info.pt.x
                                    + " y=" + info.pt.y+"\r\n");
                            bw2.write(time+"  ####  "+"x=" + info.pt.x
                                    + " y=" + info.pt.y+"\r\n");
                            bw1.flush();
                            bw2.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return lib
                .CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);//info.getPointer());
            }

            @Override
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT lParam) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
        hhk = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseHook, hMod, 0);
        int result;
        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while ((result = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
            if (result == -1) {
                System.err.println("error in get message");
                break;
            } else {
                System.err.println("got message");
                lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
                lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
            }
        }
        lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
    }
}
```

The following is error :

```
    com.sun.jna.Native$1 uncaughtException 
WARNING: JNA: Callback util.MouseHook$1@48d7f92f threw the following exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I would appreciate it that if you could help me solve the problem!!